# Scrapy IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename

Tags: python, file, file-io, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import os
from Erowid.items import ErowidItem
import codecs

class ExperiencesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "experiences"
    allowed_domains = ["www.erowid.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.erowid.org/experiences/exp_list.shtml']
    rules = [ 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_[a-zA-Z]+.shtml')), follow = True), 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/experiences/exp\.php\?ID=\d+$'),callback='parse_item', follow = True)
    ]
    def parse_item(self, response):
        selectors = response.css('div')
        for selector in selectors:
            experience = ErowidItem()
            experience['Author'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="author"]/a/text()').extract()
            experience['Title'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
            experience['Substance'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="substance"]/text()').extract()
            experience['Text'] = selector.xpath("//div[@class = 'report-text-surround']/text()").extract()
            experience['Title'] =  str(experience['Title']).replace('\\' , "")
            experience['Title'] =  str(experience['Title']).replace('?' , "")

            directory = os.path.join('Erowid/archive/',experience['Substance'][0].strip().lower())
            filename = os.path.join(directory,experience['Title'][0]+'.txt')

            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)

            with codecs.open(filename, encoding = 'utf-8', mode= 'wb') as fid:
                for symbols in experience['Text']:
                    fid.write(symbols) 
        yield experience
```

I am trying to scrape Erowid and so far this code is made so that I will create a directory and write a file primarily based on the name of an experience and the text. (By experience, I am referring to the information I am scrapping off Erowid.)

The problem is that some of the experiences have in their names characters that can't be written as a file because they contain reserved characters that can't be used in [windows filenames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

I am trying to remove all of these reserved characters which are

> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - `<` (less than)
>   - `>` (greater than)
>   - `:` (colon)
>   - `"` (double quote)
>   - `/` (forward slash)
>   - `\` (backslash)
>   - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - `?` (question mark)
>   - `*` (asterisk)

I tried to do something with the lines

```
 experience['Title'] =  str(experience['Title']).replace('\\' , "")
 experience['Title'] =  str(experience['Title']).replace('?' , "")
```

(a majority of the errors come from "\" and"?") but I still receive the error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: u'Erowid/archive/syrian rue\\Meditative Help?.txt'
```

or some other filename that I know is wrong because there isn't supposed to be a question mark or backslashes.

What am I doing wrong that triggers these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to replace the special chars. Try this:

```
filename = os.path.join(directory,experience['Title'][0]+'.txt')
filename = filename.replace('\\' , "").replace('?' , "")
```

**UPDATE**

You just want to specify a legal file name. So I come up with an idea like this.

```
directory = os.path.join('Erowid/archive/',experience['Substance'][0].strip().lower())
filename = experience['Substance']+experience['Title'][0]+'.txt'
filename = "".join([i for i in filename if i in string.ascii_letters]) 
#only use ascii letters as file name 
filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

> **string.ascii_letters**
>
> The concatenation of the ascii_lowercase and ascii_uppercase constants described below. This value is not locale-dependent.

Comment: I thought this was the answer for a while but that was because of the number of such files in which the special characters are included is a really small number. 
I still get the error/variants of the error that relate to the improper naming of the file.

Comment: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:

Same one as above but different filename

Comment: Never mind. The naming had more of the reserved characters that I haven't removed yet. Sorry for the issues.

Comment: I updated my answer to solve the problem in anther way. Try it.